# Convert docx to pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, docx

My documents are stored in a database that I want to send mail with attachments.

I want to convert stored docx to pdf.

```
var result = from c in valinor.documents
             select new
             {
                 c.document_name,
                 c.document_size,
                 c.document_content
             };

var kk = result.ToList();
for (int i = 0; i<kk.Count; i++)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(kk[i].document_content);
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(stream, kk[i].document_name + ".pdf", "application/pdf");
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
}
```

How can I convert `document_content` to pdf?

Comment: What have you tried? Here's one possibility that the search function returned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817623/converting-docx-to-pdf-using-openxml-and-pdfcreator-in-c-sharp

Comment: at 'stream'  content is doc or pdf

Comment: the stream content a docx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a third party component such as ABCpdf and (probably) Word installed on the machine and use that component to convert from docx to pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` in MIcrosoft office dll.

- add reference to your project `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`
- Check my sample of Code.

It's nice and Easy. 100% work for me.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();   
wordDocument = word.Documents.Open(savedFileName, ReadOnly: true);
wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(attahcmentPath + "/pdf" + attachment.BetAttachmentCode + ".pdf", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
word.Quit(false);
```

Comment: Saved my day! This works with both 32bit and 64bit versions