# .net pdf component

Tags: .net, winforms, pdf, components

OK, so this is my requirement...

I'm writing a winforms app that needs to create and edit Excel files on the fly and then print individual sheets to PDFs. However my application needs to be self sufficient and not rely on a PDF printer being installed.

With this in mind I need a .Net PDF printing component that I can reference in my application and call internally, passing such parameters as which page to print and where to put the file.

Does anyone know of such a thing, and if so where is it? Obviously, if anyone has done this sort of thing before, some sample code and the names of the components you used would be great.

Thanks

Comment: best answer in this other question may be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651880/save-open-xml-as-pdf

Comment: BigMike, My application, strangely in the modern world, will not have internet access and must rely entirely on running standalone. The use of a third party web service is no good to me I'm afraid.

Comment: Amyuni PDF Converter is a PDF printer that you can control programmatically, even the install/uninstall process. Maybe that would be good enough?

Answer (score 2):

We use [Aspose for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.total-for-.net/default.aspx) to work with Word documents, which we save as PDF too. Aspose provides an Excel component too. The component is not free, but it saved us a lot of work and works fine.